# How do i get dynamic properties using EPIServer webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, episerver

I'm trying to get a dynamic property using EPIServer Webservice. The only thing a see I can do is create new properties using

```
PageStoreService.RawProperty dynProperty = new PageStoreService.RawProperty();
dynProperty.IsDynamicProperty = true;
```

but I have no clue how I do to get a property. My question is this.
What is the proper way to do

```
DynamicProperty dynProperty = DynamicProperty.Load(therootnode, "MyDynamicProp");
```

using EPIServer webservice?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210553/how-to-get-startpage-rootpage-using-episerver-webservice/16211057#16211057) question. You could roll your own service to obtain this information

```
[WebService(Namespace=http://yournamespace/")]
public class PageReferenceService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{ 
    [WebMethod()]
    public PageReference GetDynamicProperty(PageReference rootNode, string propertyName)
    {
        return DynamicProperty.Load(rootNode, propertyName);
    }  
}
```

(untested)

Comment: Hi, It's similar because I asked two questions at the same time :)

Comment: You could actually look at extending the PageStoreService so you wouldn't have the additional code to call two different services